# Area of a circle which is interior to the parabola

Tags: calculus, integration, circles, conic-sections, area

I'm trying to solve the following problem:

> Find the area of the circle $x^2+y^2=8$, which is interior to the
>   parabola $y^2=2x$.

I have my own solution and I want to verify whether it is correct. My solution is to take the $1/4$ of the area of the circle, which is $\int_{0}^{\sqrt{8}}\sqrt{-x^2+8}$ and subtract the rest of the area we don't want, which is : $\int_{0}^{2}\sqrt{-x^2+8} -\sqrt{2x}$ (it is the 1/4 of the area of the circle minus the area under the parabole).

Therefore the area is $2*(\int_{0}^{\sqrt{8}}(\sqrt{-x^2+8} )- \int_{0}^{2}(\sqrt{-x^2+8} -\sqrt{2x}))$.

Is my solution correct?

Thanks

Comment: Yes the solution is correct. But you can avoid calculating the integral that gives the area of the quarter disc with center 0 and radius $\sqrt{8}$ ($\pi (\sqrt{8})^2/4$)

Comment: Please note that these integral expressions are not legitimate without the differential $dx$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at the picture below:

[image]

The area that you're after is the area of a quarter of the given circle (in this case, that's $2\pi$) plus twice the area of the region below the parabola and above the line $y=x$.

So, the area is equal to$$2\pi+2\int_0^2\sqrt{2x}-x\,\mathrm dx=2\pi+\frac43.$$

Comment: I'm calculating the following area, right? https://i.imgur.com/WiFi7cJ.png (sketched it in GeoGebra). Is my solution calculating the area I sketched? Thanks

Comment: Yes, that is the area that I computed too. But I was unable to understand your computations.

Comment: Could you please explain why do you add twice the area below the parabola and above the line y=x? That step is really not clear to me.

Comment: Because that regian appears twice, once in the upper half of the picture and once below.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at it graphically we can notice that this area is equal to the area of a semicircle minus the area under the quadratic:
$$A=\frac{\pi}{2}r^2-\int_{-r}^rxdy=\frac{\pi}{2}r^2-\int_{-r}^r\frac{y^2}{2}dy$$
Now just work this out and sub in $r=2\sqrt{2}$

Comment: But is my solution correct?

Comment: That gives the other area, from the question it is unclear which one you are trying to calculate

Comment: @ I am trying to calculate the following area: https://i.imgur.com/WiFi7cJ.png .

Comment: Yep from your diagram I believe that your solution calculates the little near-triangles on either side of this area

Comment: But why is that? The quarter of the circle is $\int_{0}^{\sqrt{8}}\sqrt{-x^2+8}$, right? And now if I subtract from the quarter the upper triangle, the area of which should be $\int_{0}^{2}\sqrt{-x^2+8} -\sqrt{2x}$,  I should get 1/2 of the area I want, right?  Not really sure where I did the mistake.

Comment: Could you please explain in your solution why is the part you subtract $\int_{-r}^r\frac{y^2}{2}dy$?